# Can COOP/COEP headers be set with meta tags (http-equiv)?

Tags: html, http-headers, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy

Can the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` headers be set with `<meta>` tags, or can they only be set with actual headers? If not, is there a list of headers which *can* be set with meta tags?

The following example logs `crossOriginIsolated: false` to the console.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy" content="require-corp">
  <meta http-equiv="Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" content="same-origin">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>COOP/COEP header test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>console.log("crossOriginIsolated:", self.crossOriginIsolated)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove those `http-equiv` meta tags and serve the file with actual HTTP headers, then it logs `crossOriginIsolated: true` (in both Chrome and Firefox). So it seems like I can't set these headers with meta tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they can't.

According to this spec, `http-equiv` supports only a few HTTP headers.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv.

That means these headers can be set only as HTTP ("actual") headers by a server. 
Supporting them in HTML would be a security bug.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please link/explain why it would be a security bug? IIRC there is no actual effect when using JavaScript to change the `http-equiv` meta tags, since they're read by the browser at page load only. Presumably if an attacker has managed to get your server to serve different HTML, then they can get it to serve different headers?

Comment: @joe
You can control `http-equiv` meta tags via js.
[This example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_meta_httpequiv.asp) at the bottom demonstrates it.

I didn't find a good explanation of how to exploit this vulnerability if it was implemented. But I was thinking about an XSS attack.

Just imagine some bank has XSS vulnerability and you can control CORS policy with some payload. Then victim can lose all of his money just by visiting 3rd party site using this vulnerability.

Comment: <meta> tags are elements of the Document. The document is created inside a OS process. COOP+COEP provide cross-origin-isolation, which isolates into a different set of processes the page to fight against Spectre attacks. This chain of dependencies make it impossible/hard to support <meta> tag.